# Looking for advice for pdf catalog conversion to html

Tags: html, pdf

I have a client that is a producer of gears and chain and such, they have a 200 page catalog that includes mostly text, tables with numbers, and a lot of diagrams.  I have to transfer the content (maintaining the formatting) to the new web site and I have begun the process of transferring the data 1 page at a time.  Here is an example of the type of content I am dealing with:

[image]

Any ideas on how I could automate such a conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**pdftocairo**

- http://poppler.freedesktop.org/

is a conversion utility, able to transcode pdf content ***as it is*** , keeping exactly layout, to several formats, one of these is **svg**

**svg** can be used on web, in html pages, mozilla browsers have an embedded svg viewer (Explorer needs the free plugin Adobe svg viewer)

it could be the best solution, however we need to take a look to size of single svg produced

to convert all pages of pdf in **svg** *(looking exactly as pdf page)* you need first to burst your pdf in single pages in a dedicated directory (then you move your source pdf one directory up)

```
pdftk yourfile.pdf burst && move yourfile.pdf ..
```

then use **pdftocairo** recursively

```
for f in *.pdf; do pdftocairo -svg $f; done
```

if size of resulting svg is not too big, they can be used in a website, otherwise you need to use

**pdftohtml**

- http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/

hoping that layout remains the same

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The problem with SVG, beyond the need for a plugin in certain browsers, is we need to have the text to be converted to straight up html so it is searchable and indexible.  I do appreciate the lengthy response however, and will likely mark it as the answer unless someone can come through with a better option.

Comment: then, pdftohtml may fit your needs; windows binaries and sourcecode available to build in other platforms, if necessary. if pdftohtml does not the trick; I think **Abbyy Finereader**, is able to produce an html output keeping faithfully the layout

Answer (score 0):

We have a tool for PDF2HTML5 at http://www.jpedal.org/html_index.php which might cover your need.